# tf-nightly-gpu and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So, I was able to get lucky and get my hands on an RTX 3070.  Unfortunately, this isn't working out as well as I would have liked for me when it comes to tensorflow. I've spent some time on google and from what I can tell, tf-nightly-gpu is the solution to my issues here.

I've installed Cuda 11/10, cuDNN, and tf-nightly-gpu, but I'm failing to make this work.  I am a rookie here, so my hope is that I'm just doing something silly. I do not get this error with tensorflow installed, but my code also doesn't use the GPU on the current build (terminology?). My understanding is that tf-nightly-gpu is my tensorflow install. Here are my includes:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\Grimace\PycharmProjects\Evo\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Grimace/PycharmProjects/Evo/HouseTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Grimace\PycharmProjects\Evo\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.layers'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grimace/PycharmProjects/Evo/HouseTest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\Grimace\PycharmProjects\Evo\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

Comment: have you tried what is mentioned in error like pip install tensorflow?

Comment: Did you installed tensorflow as backend?? pip isntall tensorflow

Comment: As others have stated, tensorflow now has GPU support built into the libray without the need to install tensorflow-gpu or tf-nightly-gpu. I followed the following guide on towards data science, but right at the end I installed tensorflow as opposed to tensorflow-gpu. This got things working for me https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781

Comment: There are issues with the RTX 3070 needing CUDA 11.x and tensorflow using 10.x. This is what has me installing tf-nightly-gpu.  Am I not correct that tf-nightly-gpu is the full tensorflow? I was thinking that Keras is looking for tensorflow and not using tf-nightly ... some type of hard coded dependency issue.  When I install the current build of tensorflow and its dependencies it doesn't work with my GPU.

Comment: After installing tf-nightly-gpu, can you import tensorflow? Does it work without issues?

Comment: Yes, it imports fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing `keras`. For tf-nightly, and all recent versions of tensorflow please import `tf.keras`. Tensorflow nightly and `tf.keras` is working well on my 3090 with CUDA 11.1.